# Best practice to store values in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am storing list of customers in session. When I reset, I wanted to know what happens to the previous cached listed, will it be destroyed automatically. Since I no longer need it, is it possible to destroy it completely and store a new value.

```
public IList<Customer> CachedCustomers
{
  set 
  { 
     HttpContext.Current.Session["Customers"] = null;//<-- Is this line required
     HttpContext.Current.Session["Customers"] = value; 
  }
}
```

Comment: @Dalorzo: the OP wanted to know if it was necessary to set to null first.

Comment: Ohh I see... yes that is not necessary :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, setting to `null` is not needed. This is no different than any variable or field in .NET. Setting to value `x`, then setting to value `y` is the same as setting to value `y`.

---

Of course, this would not apply to a property, which could run code on every set, and could do something different between setting to `null` and setting to something else.

Comment: Thank you. And is the previous cached value garbage collected since it is no longer referenced?

Comment: Every instance of a reference type will always be garbage collected some time after it is no longer referenced. There is no magic with Session state. It's not actually very special.

Answer (score 0):

For the Add session:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session["Customers"] = value;
```

For Remove the Session:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session.Contents.Remove("Customers")
```